# Significance of Aang's left eye and hand lighting up

Tags: avatar

According to the Avatar series, the solar eclipse is when the Fire Nation was at its weakest. Why do Aang's left hand and eye light up? I don't believe he is left handed, so what is the significance?

[image: Aang during the solar eclipse]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. The tattoos on Aang's body have been shown to glow whenever he enters the Avatar state. Are you asking why only his left eye and arm are glowing in the picture?

Comment: @ShayminGratitude yes exactly.  For a while I thought it signified he was a  south paw.

Comment: It's coz his left (ours right) half of the body is in the shadow, and it's a popular artistic effect to make objects "glow" in the dark and not glow on the bright side. This would be completely wrong in actuality. We've never seen only part of the avatar's glowing parts light up. This is pure artistic effect.

Comment: @Hakase I don't think that is correct take a look at this image https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51S6IxTw4AL._AC_UL320_SR238,320_.jpg

Comment: That is just bogus book cover art. If you find a screenshot from the series, that would have some credit. But I doubt there is such an occurrence.

Comment: @Hakase hahahaha that's fair.  I think your dark and light representation is probably right.

Answer (score 2):

*I haven't evidence for this answer* however, I think that it's for illustrate both *states* of the Avatar Aang:

- Aang as a *human*
- Aang in it's Avatar state.

Comment: This seems to be the case. This kind of contrast is relatively common in advertising for shows/movies these days.